# Fragment not created before being passed to FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, fragmentpageradapter

I have the following logic in a `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) object;
    myFragment.onPrimaryItemSet();
}
```

Where `MyFragment` is a support `Fragment` i.e. `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

The issue is that `myFragment.onPrimaryItemSet()` requires instance data set by the Fragment's `onCreate()` method, which has not been an issue until I recently updated from `Android Support Library 23.2.1` to `Android Support Library 24.2.0`.

I went back and discovered that starting with `Android Support Library 24.0.0` that `FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem()` is consistently called before `onCreate()` of the Fragment being passed as the `Object` parameter. Whereas in `Android Support Library 23.4.0` and before, the Fragment is consistently created first.

I read through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and [revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html), but cannot find any contract which explicitly describes the state of the Fragment when `setPrimaryItem()` is called. Therefore this very well could be a bug in the support library.

Does anyone have any solutions/workarounds for this particular issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've filed [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221339) in the AOSP issue tracker, and I'm using the following workaround until I find a better solution:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    extractArguments();
}

private void extractArguments() {
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    feature = args.getParcelable(ARG_FEATURE);
}

public void onPrimaryItemSet() {
    if (feature == null) {
        extractArguments();
    }
    // business logic
}
```